# how to display only 20 items of the result in oracle sql?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, top-n

Is it possible to display only 20 items of the whole result? 
I know of a query "rownum>=20" but that only makes the sql check only the first 20 rows in the table.
But i want the sql to check my whole table and display only the highest 20 entries.

To be clear, I have a table with job description like Title, description, agency, salary_min, salary max. I want to display the 20 highest paying jobs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "highest" 20 entries suggests a sort.  You would do something like this:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*
      from table t
      order by highestcol desc
     ) t
where rownum <= 20;
```

If you are using Oracle 12g or more recent, you can use the `fetch first` clause instead:

```
select t.*
from table t
order by highestcol desc
fetch first 20 rows only;
```

Answer (score 1):

First sort(order by) and then use rownum function.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from  
( select * 
  from emp 
  order by field ) 
where ROWNUM <= 20;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select a.fld1, a.fld2 
from 
  ( select fld1, fld2
    from mytable 
    order by 1 desc) a
where rownum <21;
```

This is one way to do what I think you asked for.  There are others ways some other posters can provide.